# Using Laplace Transforms, solve $y''-2y'+5y=e^t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Given function:

$$y''-2y'+5y=e^t$$

where $y(\pi)=2$ and $y'(\pi)=3$

I've never seen $y(\pi)=2$ and $y'(\pi)=3$ before, only $y(0)=x$ could someone help explain how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

The initial conditions in Laplace transformation can be understood as generic constants so after transforming we have

$$
s^2Y(s)-2sY(s)+5Y(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}+(s-2)C_1+C_2
$$

where $C_1 = y(0), C_2 = y'(0)$. After anti-transformation, we can use $C_1, C_2$ to determine the sought conditions at $t=\pi$.

Comment: then I get, $Y(s)=\frac{1}{(s^2-2s+s)(s-1)}+\frac{(s-2)c_1}{s^2-2s+5}+\frac{c_2}{s^2-2s+5}$. Now should I take the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: Yes. After that you can determine $C_1, C_2$ with the conditions $y(\pi)=2$ and $y'(\pi)=3$

Comment: Can I take it as, $\frac{A}{(s^2-2s+5)(s-1)}+\frac{BS-C}{s^2-2s+5}+\frac{D}{s^2-2s+5}$ and solve for this function?

Comment: Nope. Note that to determine $A,B,C$ we need three conditions and we have only two. We should proceed with $C_1, C_2$

Comment: Okay. Would it be right then if I proceed with the inverse on $Y(s)$; the first fraction would give $\frac{e^tsin(2t)}{2}*e^t$ and the following two fractions can't be carried on the inverse?

Comment: The inverse of $\frac{(s-2)C_1}{s^2-2s+5}$ is $\frac{1}{2}C_1e^t (2 \cos (2 t)-\sin (2 t))$ and for $\frac{C_2}{s^2-2s+5}$ we have $C_2e^t \sin (t) \cos (t)$ etc. so we finally obtain a solution $y = y(t,C_1,C_2)$

Comment: I was thinking about it but how did you arrange it to obtain $\frac{1}{2}C_1e^t(2cos(2t)-sin(2t))$?